# Infinite scrolling with UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uicollectionview

I want to implement infinite scrolling with `UICollectionView`.

```
//detect the bottom and add new data
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.y >= (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.size.height)) {
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
        NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    //ensure that the end of scroll is fired.
    [self performSelector:@selector(scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
        }
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    currentPage+=1;
    // First figure out how many sections there are
    NSInteger lastSectionIndex = [self.collectionView numberOfSections] - 1;

    NSInteger lastItemIndex = [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:lastSectionIndex] - 1;

    NSIndexPath *pathToLastItem = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:lastItemIndex inSection:lastSectionIndex];

    [Flickr searchFlickrForTerm:_searchBar.text page:currentPage completionBlock:^(NSString *searchTerm, NSArray *results, NSError *error) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.searchResults[searchTerm] addObjectsFromArray:results];
            [self.collectionView reloadData];
            [_collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:pathToLastItem atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
        });
    }];

}
```

The problem is that `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` is triggered each time when method `scrollToItemAtIndexPath:` executes. As a result, I see a continuos slideshow.

I tried to used `dispatch_after` with different delay, but it doesn't help.

As I understand, scrollView doesn't update it's `contentSize` after `[self.collectionView reloadData];`

How to fix it?

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution for this? It looks pretty much like what I need for my app too.

Comment: @JuanGonzález Unfortunately no.

Comment: @JuanGonzález See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use SVPullToRefresh which has built-in infinite scrolling.  Since SVPullToRefresh is built on top of `UIScrollView`, it works for anything else that is also built on top of `UIScrollView` like a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`.

https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh/